# How to return Element ID instead of [object HTMLDivElement] (Prototype.js)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, prototypejs

I know this is simple, but I can't wrap my head around it.  Currently the following code returns "[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement]" I'd like it to return "div1,div2".  Any thoughts?  Thanks guys.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to/prototype.js"></script>
<script>
function linkClick ()
{
    alert($$('div.basic'));
}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
   <div id="div1" class="basic" onclick="linkClick();"></div>
   <div id="div2" class="basic" onclick="linkClick();"></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem, there is a simple solution :

If varElement is your object containing a [HTMLDivElement] (or other DOM object) simply add '.id'

e.g.

```
varElement.id
```

Answer (score 4):

There's an optimization in prototype specifically for this:

```
$$('div.basic').pluck('id')
```

If I read your question right, you want a list of div IDs, rather than a string of ids separated by a comma.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ids = $$('div.basic').collect(function(el) { return el.id; }); //array of ids

alert(ids.join(','));
```

*collect* is another name for *map*, which is allows you to transform the elements one type of collection into another type by applying a "selector" function to each.

Comment: Just to be pedantic: you don't need the ".join(',')" part. Browsers seem to do automatically when alert()ing arrays, as the askers example shows.

Comment: I was pretty sure of that but I figured I'd play it safe rather than post non working code.  That and I was too lazy to check :)

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($$('div.basic').invoke('identify').join(',');
```

The invoke will call a function by name. The identify function will provide the id. When called on an array it will return an array of their ids. Join turns them into a string with commas in between.